# How to select all the option in listbox

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<select id="first" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="all" value="0">Select All</option>
    <option value="1">Have</option>
    <option value="2">a</option>
    <option value="3">Great</option>
    <option value="4">day</option>
</select>
```

When click `Select all` all the options in the list box have to select.Please help me to correct the below code

```
$("#first").find("option").attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: during load all the options are select.But i need to select all options only if select all option is select

Comment: as thank you ..you might like to upvote answer if it works for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to check if select all is selected.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/NEenn/1/)**

```
$('#first').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "0")
       $("option", this).attr("selected", true);
});
```

Comment: remove ; after this line if($(this).val() == "0"); , otherwise your code may not work properly

Comment: Thank you so much Pranay Rana and Adil

Answer (score 0):

just like this you can do it

```
$('#first').click( function() {
   if($(this).val() == "0")
    $(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another solution

```
$("#first").change(function () {
      $("#first option").attr("selected","selected");
});
```